# Git how to delete untracked files

Tags: git, github

My untracked files when I type `git -status` will look something like this:

[image: scrnshot]

How can I clear the untracked files? 
I tried `git clean -f` but it didn't work

Comment: It looks like you're tracking your entire home directory? That's a super bad idea.

Comment: I don't know how did it happen, I'm trying to fix it

Comment: Well for gods sake, don't. You're trying to delete your home directory and all its contents. Fix your repository by moving it to the right location.

Comment: @meagar how can I do that?

Comment: Remove the .git directory from whereever you accidentally created it

Comment: what is the syntax to remove the .git directory? I partially deleted my files already, luckily I still have it in Google Drive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60491/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-meagar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go up to a parent directory of those files, and run `git clean -f .`

Note that, the files in question appear to be quite important, and it looks like you've initialized a git project in your home directory. Removing those files is a **very bad idea**, so use `git clean` at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add `-d` if you want to delete untracked directories, and `-q` for quiet mode only reporting errors.

```
git clean -f -d -q
```